# NullReferenceException in ServiceStack's HandleResponseError on request timeout

Tags: silverlight, timeout, servicestack, nullreferenceexception

we are using the latest source code of `ServiceStack.Common` for a request that can and may exceed the server timeout. Whenever this happens I expect `JsonServiceClient.PostAsync` to invoke the `onError` callback.

Instead, `ServiceClient.Web.AsyncServiceClient.HandleResponseError<>` throws a `NullReferenceException` at line [602](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/ServiceClient.Web/AsyncServiceClient.cs#L602) on another thread which bubbles all the way up to the browser (or `App.ApplicationUnhandledException`).

A search on the web lead to fhurta's [fix](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/pull/808) from a month ago. This GitHub discussion has been closed by mythz because the fix was "to complicated". Will there be an official fix any time soon or should we get the source code and fix it ourselves? Is there another way to catch the timeout?

Comment: With regards to getting the source code and fixing it yourself it is an open source project on github, simply fork the repo and make any changes you would like.

Comment: We like to use NuGet for all our references, so a new official release would be appreciated.

Comment: Then after you're done with the fork and fix add a pull request and get it back into the official project. You can also host your own nuget repository with something like [ProGet](http://inedo.com/proget/overview).